# macOS buggy recovery download bar

Tags: macos, recovery, startup

While loading the macOS recovery online, after a few minutes the loading bar gets buggy and the timer below gets higher.

Any solution?

[image: macos recovery loading online]

There's no macOS installed but there's the Bootcamp partition

Comment: It's guesstimating the time needed. if your connection is struggling you just have to be patient.

Comment: @Tetsujin is the multiple color bar usual?

Comment: It's not a situation I've ever been in. I have all macOS installers on a server here I can just netboot or make USB sticks from. You have to bear in mind it's trying to download maybe 6GB of data - be patient with it. The slower your line, the more patience it requires.

Comment: @Tetsujin Can i boot to macos recovery with a bootable usb?

Comment: Sure you can, if you've another Mac to make it on.